# Bouncing my player further the closer I am

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm recreating the movement system from the DS game **Dragon Quest Heroes Rocket Slime** in Unity. Currently I've got pretty desirable results but it's not 100%.

One of the things that are different is that [my player bounces back from walls further on long distance slings than he does in the original game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4nWK.jpg). (left is my recreation, right is original game). Obviously, I can't find out how the game was made and the exact maths/values they use for slinging but one of the things I got from the game is that:

The player moves at constant velocity while slinging in a direction (no slow down, they just stop at a certain point)

Which led me to believe the game doesn't use traditional velocity mechanics so I made it so: 
While stretching, the players 'pVelocity' (potentialVelocity) goes up. When they let go a point create at curPlayerPosition + pVelocity is created. I then move the player at a constant velocity to that point. My idea to fix my issue of bouncing too far is by getting the distance from the position where I slung from to the end point and making the player bounce less the larger the distance and further the smaller the distance.

Problem is, I'm not really sure how to do that last part.

Here's my code:

```
Vector2 reflectedVelocity = Vector2.Reflect(pVelNormalized, foundHit.normal);
playerAnimator.SetFloat("VelocityX", reflectedVelocity.x);
playerAnimator.SetFloat("VelocityY", reflectedVelocity.y);


float DistanceFromOrigin = Vector3.Distance(slingOrigin, transform.position);
print(DistanceFromOrigin);
//ToDo: reflectedVelocity is lower the higher DistanceFromOrigin is.
```

The other solution I thought of is that maybe my idea of how the 'velocity' works in the original game is completely wrong and if so, please tell me how it actually is/looks to be actually done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reflectedVelocity is lower the higher DistanceFromOrigin is.

So `reflectedVelocity` should have an inverse relationship with `DistanceFromOrigin`

```
Vector2 reflectedVelocity = Vector2.Reflect(pVelNormalized, foundHit.normal);
float DistanceFromOrigin = Vector3.Distance(slingOrigin, transform.position);

if(DistanceFromOrigin == 0) DistanceFromOrigin = 0.00001f;//to avoid division by zero
reflectedVelocity *= (SomeConstant / DistanceFromOrigin);

playerAnimator.SetFloat("VelocityX", reflectedVelocity.x);
playerAnimator.SetFloat("VelocityY", reflectedVelocity.y);
```

You may use a linear relationship instead of non-linear:

```
reflectedVelocity *= (SomeConstant - DistanceFromOrigin);
```